# How do I capture when a user presses CTRL + S?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website which can save sessions but I think buttons are ugly so I thought that shortcuts would be easier, and I would prefer the onkeydown HTML tag function. The shortcut I want to use is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. For example

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == CTRL+S) saveSession()">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm in love with the `Mousetrap` library: https://craig.is/killing/mice.
It normalizes keybindings with great browser support.

For example:

```
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+s', function(e) {
    alert('Save!');
});
```

Since ctrl isn't used for saving on a Mac, you can bind multiple key combinations to the save function, e.g.

```
Mousetrap.bind(['ctrl+s', 'command+s'], function(e) {
    alert('Save!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Added a solution for Windows and Mac, previously answered for Mac only.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 83 && (navigator.platform.match('Mac') ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('captured');
  }
});
```

Add the above code in a `function` and call it `onkeydown`. Some explanation of how the code works..

First we check the keycode for `s` which is `83`, and later, we check if the user also presses `ctrl` key if on Windows using `e.ctrlKey` (e is the event here) and if it's mac then check for the `metaKey`.

Last, am using `(e) => {}` is an ES6 shorthand for `function(e) {}`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xb8t2zey/3/)